# Legato Networker automatic report

Tags: automation, backup

On our middle sized company we are using Legato Networker, and now we would like to have some sheduled reports.

We already know about some software that can handle that, but it's not a good time to buy new stuff.

I'm just starting to look after this issue, so I do not know where to start, so I decided to ask for advice or help here.

Our legato backups a Microsoft Windows 2008 R2 infrastructure, and also 50 linux machines.

If I go to the Legato Manager Console I can have some graphical reports with lots of useful information, but this must be done by hand.

We would like to do this on automated way, so I will just recieve a mail with a report, or the report is created inside a folder.

We don't care much if this is done from windows sheduled tasks, or using a linux client and it's cron engine.

Does anyone done anything like this with Legato before? Can someone give me some tips and hits?

Many thanks for your help in advance. 
Also, understanding that this is not a paranoid issue, and many people can found it useful on the future, I'll post whatever I find.

Thanks.

Marc

Comment: That thing still exists? What is the media used to backup?

Comment: We use an IBM T4000 LTO4 tape library. Legato it's buggy as hey, I even suggested to my boss to migrate all to another thing like netapp or even amanda. :$   But it works if you don't touch it.

Answer (score 1):

report script to put on cron:
https://agora.cs.illinois.edu/display/~mussulma/quantity-report.pl

other stuff:
https://agora.cs.illinois.edu/display/~mussulma/EMC+Legato+Networker+Admin+Tools

For further usage.